How to calculate the specific heat jump for a van der Waals gas at a non-critical volume?
I am currently self-studying Statistical Physics by Professor Schwabl and encountered a problem in the book (problem 5.5) that has significantly challenged my understanding. The problem is brief but has caused me much contemplation:
"Calculate the jump in the specific heat $c_v$ for a van der Waals gas at a specific volume of $v \neq v_c$."
Here, $v_c$ is the volume at the critical point.
My initial reaction was to question the problem's premise. Given the definition of the specific heat at constant volume, we have
$$c_v = T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_v,\tag1$$
and from Maxwell's relations, by taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $v$, we get
$$\left(\frac{\partial c_v}{\partial v}\right)_T = T\left(\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial T^2}\right)_v,\tag2$$
Following the van der Waals equation of state,
$$\left(P + \frac{a}{v^2}\right)(v - b) = RT,\tag3$$
and since $T$ and $P$ are linearly related, the right side of equation (2) equals zero. This implies that the derivative of $c_v$ with respect to $v$ is zero, making $c_v$ a function of $T$ only,
$c_v = c_v(T),\tag4$
raising the question of whether seeking the specific heat jump at a particular volume is meaningless—this forms my first confusion.
On the other hand, I believe that the calculation of the specific heat at constant volume $c_v$ usually involves differentiating the state equation and considering energy conservation and changes in the state of matter. However, significant changes in $c_v$, such as during phase transitions from gas to liquid or near critical points, do not seem applicable to all specific volumes $v$. This aspect also contributes to my misunderstanding of the problem, leading me to wonder if I have misinterpreted the question or if there is a more advanced theory that I have overlooked in my studies.
I have discussed this issue with others, who think that there isn't a simple formula that directly yields the $c_v$ for a van der Waals gas; it might need to be determined through experimental data or estimated using more advanced thermodynamic models and statistical mechanics methods. This has led me to an impasse in my thoughts, and I am unsure how to further tackle this problem.
I would be immensely grateful if you could help resolve the doubts I have encountered in my self-study.
Here's the screenshot of the original problem:


By "jump," Schwabl means the difference between heat capacities upon a phase change, yes? Your finding that the heat capacity $c_v$ is independent of the specific volume $v$ in the gas phase is consistent with Schwabl's Eq. (5.4.21a) ($c_v=\frac{3}{2}Nk$), also for the gas phase. You can't start to draw conclusions about the so-called jump, though, until you explore the other side of the phase transition—would you agree?

Thank @Chemomechanics for your clarification! Your explanation helped me understand that the “jump” in specific heat, as discussed by Schwabl, indeed refers to the change associated with a phase transition.
